# Break from a loop with an external method

Tags: c++, loops, arduino

I am programming with an Arduino and my program contains a lot of while loops. When Arduino receives a character it must do some calculations and break from a loop that it has been in when it received a character. I will give you a simpler example (presume i and j are set to 0):

```
while (i < 256)
{
    // some calculations #1
    i++;

    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        setStringOne = "string one"
        setStringTwo = "string two"
        setStringThree = "string three"
        setStringFour = "string four"

        break;
    }
}

while (j < 256)
{
    // some calculations #2
    j++;

    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        setStringOne = "string one"
        setStringTwo = "string two"
        setStringThree = "string three"
        setStringFour = "string four"

        break;
    }
}
```

You can see that in both cases I used the same piece of code in the if sentences. What I want it to be able to write something like this.

```
while (i < 256)
{
    // some calculations #1
    i++;

    if (Serial.available() > 0)
        checkAndBreak();
}

while (j < 256)
{
    // some calculations #2
    j++;

    if (Serial.available() > 0)
        checkAndBreak();
}

void checkAndBreak()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        setStringOne = "string one"
        setStringTwo = "string two"
        setStringThree = "string three"
        setStringFour = "string four"

        break;
    }
}
```

To break for a loop with an external method.

It gives me an error "break statement not within loop or switch", which is expected since it doesn't know which loop to break from but I was just wondering if it is possible to make something along those lines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a `checkAndBreak` macro or exceptions or `longjmp`.

Comment: Changing your loop condition to `while (j < 256 && Serial.available() <= 0 )` should enable you to get rid of the break

Comment: Oh, I haven't even thought about that. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using exceptions?

Comment: I have never worked with exceptions on Arduino, so I don't really have an idea of how could I implement them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't break like that, so no way. Just balance out what each method does:

```
while (i < 256)
{
      if (Serial.available() > 0)
      {
             setThoseStrings();
             break;
      }
      i++;
}
```

Alternatively

```
while (i < 256)
{
        if (checkSerialAndSetStrings())
        {
               break;
        }
        i++;
}
```

This looks shorter but if you ever need to set strings in other situations (e.g. setting them when a timer runs out), you'll just waste time removing the serial check from `checkSerialAndSetStrings` and updating your code. I'd go with #1.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will have to make it like this. Thanks for the answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do similar tricks with `return`, though it might look little less obvious for some old-school programmers.
Assuming `Serial.avaiable()` returns unsigned integer, you *don't* want to check it *before* your calculations, and you *do* actually need the updated `i,j` counters as the post-effects when you update your strings, I would do it this way:

```
// Obviously this function somehow has
// access to the strings being modified
// And possibly to some other state affected by calculations #1 and #2
// I'm leaving it similar to how you've written it
// for the sake of clarity
bool checkAndBreak()
{
    if (!Serial.available())
        return false;

    setStringOne   = "string one";
    setStringTwo   = "string two";
    setStringThree = "string three";
    setStringFour  = "string four";

    return true;
}

size_t i = 0, j = 0;

do {
    // calculations #1
} while (++i, !checkAndBreak() && i < 256);

do {
    // calculations #2
} while (++j, !checkAndBreak() && j < 256);
```

Note that in the end `i,j` yield the same values as in your example.
Another funny way is:

```
// define `i,j` outside of the loops if you need their final values
// !i and !j checks are to make sure checkAndBreak() 
// won't execute before the loop body
for (size_t i = 0; (!i || !checkAndBreak()) && i < 256; ++i)
    // calculations #1
for (size_t j = 0; (!j || !checkAndBreak()) && j < 256; ++j)
    // calculations #2
```

You can also extract your calculations into functions:

```
void calc1(size_t i) { ... }
void calc2(size_t j) { ... }

for (size_t i = 0; i < 256 && (calc1(i++), !checkAndBreak()); );
for (size_t j = 0; j < 256 && (calc2(j++), !checkAndBreak()); );
```

This way you get your `< 256` check first, then `calc1/calc2` are executed with the old `i/j` values, afterwards the `i/j` value gets incremented, and then the check is performed. If the check returns true, the whole `for` loop terminates.

Beware that those practices are not aligned with the KISS principle, so may you adjust your code, pre-conditions and post-effects to simply write

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    // do the calculations #1
    // now check the side effects of those calculations
    if (serialCheckedAndStateChanged())
        break;
}
// The same for #2
```

Comment: Really helpful examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example why you should not use "break", "continue" or multiple return statements within a method/procedure. You are not able to extract methods to reduce redundancies. My advice is to reformulate your code to work without break-statements.

I would try following approach:

```
do {
    // some calculations #1
    i++;
} while (i < 256 && Serial.available() == 0)

if (Serial.available() > 0)
{
    setStringOne = "string one"
    setStringTwo = "string two"
    setStringThree = "string three"
    setStringFour = "string four"
}

do {
    // some calculations #2
    j++;

} while (j < 256 && Serial.available() == 0)

if (Serial.available() > 0)
{
    setStringOne = "string one"
    setStringTwo = "string two"
    setStringThree = "string three"
    setStringFour = "string four"
}
```

Now you are able to improve the the code:

Extract methods and apply the template pattern to the calculation code (as far as possible in Arduino) to reduce redundancy.

Example of extracted method:

```
void determineString()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        setStringOne = "string one"
        setStringTwo = "string two"
        setStringThree = "string three"
        setStringFour = "string four"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I also rewritten my code to use no breaks and I got rid of some redundancies.

Comment: You assume that `Serial.available()` has no side effects and comes at no cost, thus calling it again after each loop. If you do want to get rid of breaks, then the proper approach would be to extract each loop into a function making the calculations and returning `true` when `Serial.available() > 0` or `false` when the iteration ends.

Comment: You are right: That "Serial.available()" "[...] has no side effects and comes at no cost[...]" was a guess. I expected the method to do how it is named. And AFTER I looked it up my assumption seems to be not so far away from reality. (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available).

Comment: Let's assume "Serial.available()" is expensive. Then I would not use boolean returning functions that signals proper execution or any other hidden semantic either. I would introduce code fragments that represent caching.